# Perl Search for string and print out line

Tags: perl

I want to write a perl script that ask the user for a string and then finds the lines that contains that string and prints them.
This is what i have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub main
{
    print "First name or Last Name or any portion: ";
    my $name = <STDIN>;
    my $file = '/home/jake/Downloads/phones';
    open(FH, $file) or die("File $file not found");
     
    while(my $String = <FH>)
    {
        if($String =~ $name)
        {
            print "$String \n";
        }
    }
    close(FH);
}
main();
```

Whenever I try this the terminal doesnt print anything. Is there anything that I could do to fix that?

Comment: `open` can fail for many reasons other than "not found".  The reason is available in `$!`.  Use `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!\n";`

Comment: A classic: you didn't remove the linefeed (newline) from your input; need `chomp $name;` after the `$name` has been read from `<STDIN>`.  This way `$name` has a newline character at its end which isn't in the `$string` so it can never match. There's more here but try this first, perhaps to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub main
{
    print "First name or Last Name or any portion: ";
    my $name = <STDIN>; 
    chomp $name;
    my $file = '/home/jake/Downloads/phones';
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!\n";

    while(my $string = <$fh>)
    {
        if($string =~ /$name/)
        {
            print "$string\n";
        }
    }
    close($fh);
}
main();
```

- You need to omit the new line character using `chomp`.
- Use a modern way to read a file, using a lexical filehandle.